# How do I access the fields of a custom object with a standard controller?

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, standardcontroller

I have a custom object called "Shows."  I'm writing a VisualForce page to display some custom data.  My code is:

```
<apex:page standardController="Show__c">
    <apex:pageBlock id="thePageBlock" >
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Private Event Detail" columns="1">
            <p>Account: {!show.PE_Account__c}</p>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

When I save this, I get the following error message:

```
Error: Unknown property 'Show__cStandardController.show'
```

I'm not using an extension here because as I understand from the documentation, I shouldn't need one.  But perhaps I'm understanding it incorrectly.  The Visualforce documentation says:

> Salesforce includes standard controllers for every standard and custom
>   object.

and

> Every standard controller includes a getter method that returns the
>   record specified by the id query string parameter in the page URL.
>   This method allows the associated page markup to reference fields on
>   the context record by using {!***object***} syntax, where object is the
>   lowercase name of the object associated with the controller.

I take this all to mean that I should be able to access data using the {!***show***} syntax.  Clearly that doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried {!show__c.PE_Account__c}??

Comment: I tried a bunch of permutations and combinations. The answer below nails it. I wish the documentation was more clear for newbies.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use the full Object API name, which is the same as the name of the standard controller:

```
<apex:page standardController="Show__c">
    <apex:pageBlock id="thePageBlock" >
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Private Event Detail" columns="1">
            <p>Account: {!Show__c.PE_Account__c}</p>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```