# How do I add info from a custom object to my visual force page when I'm already using a standard controller?

Tags: visualforce

Here is what I am trying to do.

I have a visualforce page, I have information from the account object populating in a table.

I'd also like to populate information from my custom object to that visualforce page. How do I do that? I would be okay using another table, I'm not picky on how that information shows up just as long as it works.

My code is simple, I'm a beginner.

```html
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="amanda">
    <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!amanda}" var="acc">
       <apex:column value="{!acc.Name}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

The API name of the custom object would be Milestone__c, I would like to bring over name, Where_are_we__c, and Name__c

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I access the fields of a custom object with a standard controller?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/19204/how-do-i-access-the-fields-of-a-custom-object-with-a-standard-controller)

Comment: Have you tried the [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/visualforce_fundamentals)?

Comment: I'm super confused. On trailhead now, looking at an extension possibly but not quite understanding.

Comment: @identigral That doesn't answer this question.

Comment: @sfdcfox That depends on how you read the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use Apex or the API to get this data. Visualforce itself can't do what you're trying to do without some help.

```
<apex:page controller="MyPageController">
  <apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="accountRecord">
      <apex:column value="{!accountRecord.Name}" headerValue="Name" />
      <apex:column> 
        <apex:dataTable value="{!accountRecord.Milestones__r}" var="milestone">
          <apex:column value="{!milestone.Name}" headerValue="Name" />
          <apex:column value="{!milestone.Where_are_we__c}" headerValue="Where Are We?" />
          <apex:column value="{!milestone.Name__c}" headerValue="Custom Name" />
        </apex:dataTable>
      </apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

And for the Apex code:

```
public class MyPageController {
  public Account[] getAccounts() {
    return [
      SELECT Name, (
        SELECT Name, Where_Are_We__c, Name__c 
        FROM Milestones__r
      )
      FROM Account
    ];
  }
}
```

Note that there's a limit of 50,000 records unless you use the "readOnly" property on `apex:page`. You can also add database filters to selectively choose which records you want to show.

Comment: So you made an extension right? the top code goes onto the visual force and the bottom goes to the extension class?

Comment: @ArtimusFowl No, this is more straight-forward. Instead of a standard controller, we use a custom controller (`controller` instead of `standardController`). The first block is the Visualforce, the second is the Apex code. This code is meant to be illustrative, not prescriptive, though. I've left out things like error handling and security to keep it simple.

Comment: so where does the apex code go? sorry, i'm trying to understand. i was told i need to make an extension and come up with a SOQL query. I do have a relationship between account and my custom object milestone__c

Comment: @ArtimusFowl you don't need an extension. This code should copy as-is with no modification. The Apex Code goes into an Apex Class, the Visualforce goes into a Visualforce Page. There is no extension here, as we are not using a standard controller on this example.